# How do I make multiple insertions into a SQLite DB from UIPath

Tags: sqlite, uipath

I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple entries that I want to insert into an SQLite DB from UIPath.  How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask. Show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it one of two ways.  For both methods, you will need to use the Excel Read Range to put the excel into a table.

Scenario 1:  You could read the table in a for each loop, line by line, converting each row to SQL and use a Execute non-query activity.  This is too long, and if you like O notation, this is an O(n) solution.

Scenario 2:  You could upload the entire table (as long as its compatible with the DB Table) to the database.

you will need Database > Insert activity
You will need to provide the DB Connection (which I answer in another post how to create)
Then enter the sqlite database table you want to insert into in Quotes
And then enter the table name that you have created or pulled from another resource in the last field
Output will be an integer (Affected Records)

For O Notation, this is an O(1) solution.  At least from our coding perspective